# MySQL rejects connections with auth_socket

Tags: mysql

I recently replaced an installation of MariaDB on a CentOS 7 server with MySQL Community Edition 5.7. The previous installation was configured to allow socket peer authentication for the root user, and I attempted to replicate that same setup with the new installation.

After reinstalling MySQL and re-initializing the database directory (`/var/lib/mysql`), I enabled the `auth_socket` plugin in `/etc/my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

plugin-load-add=auth_socket.so
```

I then connected to MySQL using the auto-generated temporary root password and set the `root` user to use `auth_socket`:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH auth_socket;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

After making this change, when I attempt to connect to the database with `sudo mysql -u root`, I get an "access denied" error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I'm also unable to log in with the temporary password that worked before I updated the user.

Is there some subtle configuration step that I could be missing?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you restarted the server after the changes to the cnf-File you could try to add the second line in the `.cnf` so that the server fails if the plugin does not initialize successfully:

```
plugin-load-add=auth_socket.so
auth_socket=FORCE_PLUS_PERMANENT
```

This way you may be able to narrow the problem down. Or you could try to register the plugin at runtime from within mysql:

```
INSTALL PLUGIN auth_socket SONAME 'auth_socket.so';
```

Answer (score 3):

I cannot comment above answer, so here my "own" answer:

```
INSTALL PLUGIN auth_socket SONAME 'auth_socket.so';
```

doesn't work, at least not with MariaDB (5.5) on CentOS 7. For Mariadb, it should read:

```
INSTALL PLUGIN unix_socket SONAME 'auth_socket.so';
```

(see documentation here https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/

Afterwards, do a

```
update user set plugin = 'unix_socket' where user='root'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

restart mariadb, and login can be without password for user root (e.g. for crontab backups)

Comment: That looks like it probably would fix it. Unfortunately, I'm not working on the project that prompted this question anymore, so I can't confirm the solution, but it would make sense based on the docs.